Quadratic form of a matrix where non-standard decomposition is known
Let $1\le m<<n$ for integers $m,n$. I have two symmetric matrices of size $n\times n$, say $A$ and $B$. My goal here is to know a simple form, or an upper bound on the following quadratic form:
$$
\mathbb{1}^T\;(A+B)^{-1} \; \mathbb{1}
$$
where $\mathbb{1}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a vector consists of $1$.
The matrix $A$ is full rank and has a known eigenvalue decomposition $A=P\Lambda P^*$ where $P$ consists of eigenvectors of $A$ and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues. We can actually assume $A$ and $A+B$ are positive definite.
The matrix $B$ is rank-$m$, and a decomposition $B=C^T C$, where $C$ is $m\times n$, is given.
Using these given decompositions, $P,\Lambda, C$, I want to know another expression of $\mathbb{1}^T\;(A+B)^{-1} \; \mathbb{1}$.
Using Woodbury's identity, I can rewrite
$$
(A+B)^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^{-1} C^T(I^{(m\times m)}+C A^{-1} C^T)^{-1} C A^{-1}
$$
Because I know $A^{-1}=P\Lambda^{-1} P^*$, and I can actually obtain $\mathbb{1}^T\;A^{-1} \mathbb{1}$, my only problem is to get another form of
$$
  C^T(I^{(m\times m)}+C A^{-1} C^T)^{-1} C
$$
analytically. Would there be any known identity for this matrix? Any comments and references would be appreciated.
